# Intellij Idea does not show symbol errors for calling enum members

Tags: intellij-idea

After updating my IntelliJ idea community edition to 2018, symbol errors are not detected in the editor. also, I couldn't use alt enter to fix and generate automatically a member in another class.

I called a member `(MainWindow)` of `MetaModulesEntFx class (enum class)`, the idea does not understand whether or not that member (enum member) exists

[image: showing calling member]

this is MetaModulesEntFx

[image: metamodulesentfx enum class]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it a Maven project?

Comment: yes, maven project

Comment: Have you tried to 'Reimport All Maven Projects'? Maven Projects tab->spinner icon at top-left

Comment: No reimporting all maven projects didnt solve my problem

Comment: Also i have multiple modules in the project

Comment: I created new project, and imported the module,but the problem isnt fixed 

Comment: @bmtncy Make sure Power Save mode is not enabled in the File menu. Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the issue persists.